# Code printing out multiple answers

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some stuff for my JScript class and I can't see how my code is printing multiple instances of my document.write. Any help?

```
memberNumber = prompt("How many people will be staying?");
memberOfAAA = prompt("Are the members part of AAA?");
roomView = prompt("Do you want a room with a view?");
Number(memberNumber);   

if(memberOfAAA === "yes" || "Yes", memberNumber > 5 && memberNumber < 3, roomView === "yes") 
{
roomCost = (costRoom12 - (costRoom12 * percent1)+(costRoom12 * viewCost));
document.write("Total cost per night is $" + roomCost );
}if (memberOfAAA === "yes" || "Yes", memberNumber > 5 && memberNumber < 3, roomView === "no" || "No") 
{
roomCost = (costRoom12 - (costRoom12 * percent1));
document.write("Total cost per night is $" + roomCost );}

if(memberOfAAA === "no" || "No" , memberNumber > 5 && memberNumber < 3, roomView === "yes" || "Yes") 
{
roomCost = (costRoom12 + (costRoom12 * viewCost));
document.write("Total cost per night is $" + roomCost );
}if(memberOfAAA === "no" || "No" , memberNumber > 5 && memberNumber < 3, roomView === "no" || "No") 
{
roomCost = (costRoom12);
document.write("Total cost per night is $" + roomCost );
}
if (memberOfAAA === "yes" || "Yes", memberNumber > 5 && memberNumber < 3, roomView === "yes" || "Yes") {
roomCost = (costRoom34 - (costRoom34 * percent2) + (costRoom34 * viewCost)); 
document.write("Total cost per night is $" + roomCost );
}
if (memberOfAAA === "yes" || "Yes", memberNumber > 5 && memberNumber < 3, roomView === "no" || "No") {
roomCost = (costRoom34 - (costRoom34 * percent2));
document.write("Total cost per night is $" + roomCost );
}
if(memberOfAAA === "no" && memberNumber > 5 && memberNumber < 3, roomView === "yes" || "Yes") {
roomCost = (costRoom34 + (costRoom34 * viewCost)); 
document.write("Total cost per night is $" + roomCost );
}
if(memberOfAAA === "no" || "No", memberNumber > 5 && memberNumber < 3, roomView === "no" || "No") {
roomCost = costRoom34;
document.write("Total cost per night is $" + roomCost );
}
if(memberOfAAA === "Yes" || "yes", memberNumber > 7 && memberNumber < 4, roomView === "yes" || "Yes") {
roomCost = (costRoom56 - (costRoom56 * percent3) + (costRoom56 * viewCost))

}
if(memberOfAAA === "yes" || "Yes", memberNumber > 7 && memberNumber < 4, roomView === "no" || "No") {
roomCost = (costRoom56 - (costRoom56 * percent3)); 
document.write("Total cost per night is $" + roomCost );
}
if(memberOfAAA === "no" || "No", memberNumber > 7 && memberNumber < 4, roomView === "yes" || "Yes") {
roomCost = (costRoom56 + (costRoom56 * viewCost)); 
document.write("Total cost per night is $" + roomCost );
}
if(memberOfAAA === "no" || "No", memberNumber > 7 && memberNumber < 4, roomView === "no" || "No") {
roomCost = (costRoom56);
document.write("Total cost per night is $" + roomCost );
}
```

It's supposed to only print one string as defined by the variables one inputs, but it's printing out all the strings.

Comment: You should post some code.

Comment: woops, forgot that part, fixed

Answer (score 1):

Your if statements are always evaluating to true because

```
if (memberOfAAA === "yes" || "Yes" ... )
```

Should be

```
if (memberOfAAA === "yes" || memberOfAAA === "Yes" ...)
```

Also you should be using an if/else if statements.

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a shot!